# Programatically accessing RDL files- (Exception thrown)

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I have more than 1000 rdl files and want to document the name of datasources in each of them. I was experimenting on loading and accessing a single rdl file programatically in C#
and tried the following code line.

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel.Report.Load("C:\\abc.rdl");
```

But below exception is thrown.  why this exception is thrown?

---

> System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled   Message="Deserialization
>   failed: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportDesign.Common, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Line 5,
>   position 6."   Source="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer.Controls" 
>   LineNumber=5   LinePosition=6   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel.Serialization.RdlReader.ReadRoot(Type
>   type)

Comment: Are you sure that the version of the RDL's matches the version of SSRS that you have installed to this machine?

Answer (score 2):

> The system cannot find the file specified.

I would guess maybe you're missing a dependency or something. Sure the Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportDesign.Common assembly is on your system?

Comment: I have added all the required dlls. so that is not the issue I guess

Answer (score 2):

Try using fuslogvw.exe to see which assembly is missing. Or just load RDL into XmlDocument or XDocument and use XPath or XLinq.